# projectq code hangs with only 8 qibts

Tags: programming, simulation, projectq

I have written a simple projectq code with 8qbits in order to perform full addition but it gets stuck somewhere between without generating any error message. It worked fine for 4 qbits.

```
def full_adder(eng,x,y,length,s,cin,cout):
    aux = eng.allocate_qureg(4)

    print("Going into loop to perform operations \n")

    for i in range(length):
        Toffoli | (x[i], y[i], aux[1])
        CNOT | (x[i], s[i])
        CNOT | (y[i], s[i])
        Toffoli | (cin, s[i], aux[0])
        CNOT | (cin, s[i])
        CNOT | (aux[0], aux[2])
        CNOT | (aux[1], aux[2])
        Toffoli | (aux[0], aux[1], aux[3])
        CNOT | (aux[2], cout)
        CNOT | (aux[3], cout)
    
    print("Addition completed going out of the loop \n")

def main(eng):
    x = eng.allocate_qureg(8)  # first
    y = eng.allocate_qureg(8)  # second
    s = eng.allocate_qureg(8)  # sum
    cout = eng.allocate_qureg(1) # carry out
    cin = eng.allocate_qureg(1) # carry in

    length=8

    input1=0xab
    input2=0x12

    Round_constant_XOR(eng,x,input1,length)
    Round_constant_XOR(eng,y,input2,length)
    print("About to start Addition \n")
    full_adder(eng,x,y,length,s,cin,cout)
    print("Addition Completed, printing results \n")
    print_state(eng,s,length)

Simulate = MainEngine()
main(Simulate)
Simulate.flush()
```

Below is the output

```
(Note: This is the (slow) Python simulator.)
About to start Addition 

Going into loop to perform operations 

Addition completed going out of the loop
```

Once it gets out of the `full_adder` function, it gets stuck, and nothing happens after this.